# Apache Camel Specify _id in Elasticsearch connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-camel

I'm using the elastic rest component https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/elasticsearch-rest-component.html
I'm not able to specify the id of a document in any way. The documentation seems to have a lack in this sense

the code is more o less like

```
from(RAW_ROUTE)
            .process(new RawProcessor())
            .to("elasticsearch://local?operation=Index&indexName=raw&indexType=_doc")
    ;
```

The RawProcessor set a Map as body of the exchange object

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`_id` can be set with `indexId` header.

See [Message Operations](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/elasticsearch-rest-component.html#_message_operations):

> Index: Adds content to an index and returns the content’s indexId in the body. You can set the indexId by setting the message header with the key "indexId"

You can find example usage in unit test [`ElasticsearchIndexTest#testIndexWithIDInHeader`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-elasticsearch-rest/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchIndexTest.java#L65).